# Element "style" not allowed as child of element "div" in this context in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, validation, syntax-error

I ran a test through The w3.org validator. And it gave me the following error "Element "style" not allowed as child of element "div" in this context". I do not know how to approach this in WordPress. My website runs on the Avada Theme

Element "style" not allowed as child of element "div" in this context
At line 371, column 953

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: can you please provide your HTML, CSS, and Javascript along with some additional context? The error gave the location of the code so that section is critcal to see, to be able to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I know how to fix it on a html site. But I dont how approach this on wordpress

Comment: Fundamentally the troubleshooting is the same. Without seeing code or more context or even just what you have tried its very hard to provide any assistance. Perhaps a link to the page you are having issues on would be a good place to start.